# Why can't I save a document's property inside Document Set

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set, site-column

I am seeing this behaviour and wanted to check if it was normal. I have document set which has a shared column named "Book". However for some of the documents inside the document set I need to be able to change the value of it. I can edit and save the column but the changes I made doesn't stay and revert backs to the value document set has. Is this a known and correct behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared metadata is applied to all documents in the document set, this is by design. It sounds like you would need an ordinary column for this metadata rather than using shared metadata:

[Introduction to Document Sets](https://support.microsoft.com/office/introduction-to-document-sets-3dbcd93e-0bed-46b7-b1ba-b31de2bcd234)

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, there is no situation where the changes will not be preserved. My setup is to add the shared Book column as Shared column, what are you using for the properties of the column? Shared metadata? You might be able to narrow down the problem and see if the same is the case in other libraries or create another shared column to see.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Is there any progress on this thread? Please feel free to let me know.